# How to search the elements in a column of a csv in a column of another csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file with 10 million rows and some columns as `AuthorId    PaperId    Name`.
I want to find each AuthorId  in this file in another .csv file having similar columns. I want to label those found in second csv as '1' else '2'.
Whats the best pythonic way to accomplish this?

I wrote 50 lines code to accomplish above by simply using for loops and using pandas for loading data. I got what i wanted, but the time taken for the whole code to run was around 6 hours. All i want to know is if there is any small pre defined module or a function in pandas/numpy which i dont know about?

**EDIT:** DSM already posted the answer, but i would like to post my code with which i was trying to do same thing. FILE SIZE = 536mb(both)

```
import pandas as pd

data1=pd.read_csv('sample8.csv')
data2=pd.read_csv('Merged_Data2.csv')
list1=[]
count1=0
for i in data1['Author id']:
    count2=0
    check=0
    for j in data2['Author id']:
        if i==j:                      #compare two elements
            check = 1
            list1.append('1')         #if found append '1' to list
            count2+=1
            break
    if check == 0:           #check if element was found in other file or not and append '2'
        list1.append('2')
    count1+=1 
    print count1
print list1

data1["Label"] = list1            #create new column
print data1
```

Comment: First of all attempt this yourself, google for `Python csv`, it's a module dedicated for working with csv files. Post some of your code to ask about specific problems and show that you've done something. Are the files small enough so that you can read them into memory simultaneously?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. aleksander!. I surely did something, infact i got what i want. But the time taken by my code was in hours. I was just asking for some short method to accomplish the above. And i did googled much on it but cant find any short way. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: The edit is good, but can you post the code that you're working with? Also, it would be nice to know how big the input file is (100MB? 1000MB?)

Comment: @Prince sure I understand but it's impossible to help you make your code faster without knowing what it looks like.

Comment: Albeit DSM already posted the answer. I have attached my code for reference. Any other method to do same are welcome..:). Being new to coding that was best i could think of...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using `pandas`, you should be able to do this in seconds, not hours.  You can use `isin` to quickly build a Series telling you whether the AuthorId is in both:

```
>>> in_both = df1["AuthorId"].isin(df2["AuthorId"])
>>> in_both.value_counts()
False    9900514
True       99486
dtype: int64
>>> in_both.head(5)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: AuthorId, dtype: bool
```

And then you can make a new column out of this:

```
>>> df1["new_column"] = in_both.astype(int).replace({True: 1, False: 2})
>>> df1.head(5)
    AuthorId Name    PaperId  new_column
0  617812672    B  424981777           1
1  757076542    B  998817530           2
2  625856763    B  350728063           2
3  124624974    B  734725334           2
4    2719471    B  400606485           2
```

Elapsed time for me on two 10M-row frames is about 5s.  You could be faster or slower by a factor of several depending on processor speed and the number of distinct AuthorIds, but it certainly shouldn't take hours.  Probably you were using a linear search for membership.

Comment: Thanks DSM. This is exactly what i was looking for. Yeah  i was using linear search using for loops only(m new to coding, this was the best that i could do). I always believed python would have something better for this.:).